# How can depend modules to each other?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, module

[image: appmodule]   [image: usecasemodule]

UploadImageUseCase.kt

```
 class UploadImageUseCase(
        private val requestCreationRepository: DocumentRepository,
        private val context: Context,
        activityResultPlugin: ActivityResultPlugin
    ) : UseCase<UploadImageAction, UploadImageResult> {
}
```

ActivityResultPlugin.kt

```
class ActivityResultPlugin {
    private val behaviorEventRelay: BehaviorRelay<Event> = BehaviorRelay.create()

    fun behaviorEvent(event: Event) {
        behaviorEventRelay.accept(event)
    }

    fun behaviorEventRelay() = behaviorEventRelay
    fun clear() {
        //behaviorEventRelay.accept(EmptyEvent)
    }
}
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
implementation project(path: ':ui')
implementation project(path: ':usecase')
implementation project(path: ':data')
implementation project(path: ':entity')
```

When I added `implementation project(path: ':app')` inside `build.gradle(:usecase)`, I can import `ActivityResultPlugin` but it get error

> Circular dependency between the following tasks:

Then how can I use `ActivityResultPlugin` in UploadImageUseCase in UseCase module?

Comment: General advice: maybe rethink your module structure. Don't split them by ui/usecase/data/... But by features.

If you want to keep your current structure:
You need a module on top of app and usecase, which knows both modules. This module defines interfaces which can be implemented by the individual modules. The modules implement these interfaces and return an instance to the "Top" module. The "Top" Module can than inject the interface implementation into the other modules where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can introduce a `Plugin` interface in the `:usecase` module and let the `ActivityResultPlugin` implement it.

Comment: Trying to implement it. Thinking how.